# Relation between models in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model, backbone-relational

I'm looking for the correct backbone structure to achieve the following:

Two server APIs:

- `GET api/event/4` : returns the event object with id 4.
- `GET api/event/4/registrations` : returns the list of registration objects belonging to event with id 4

I want a view displaying the event object and the list of registrations.

This is very straightforward but I cannot figure out how to organize my Event and Registration models.
Should I use backbone-relational?

My Event model is currently like this:
(the collection is expected to contain the next 10 events from now).

How should I define my Registration model and how will I initialize it, knowing that it is always in the context of an Event model?

```
var app = app || {};

app.EventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: app.API_server + 'event'
});


app.EventCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.EventModel,
    url: app.API_server + 'event',
    initialize: function(){
        dt = new Date();
        start_dt = dt.toISOString();
        this.fetch({
            data: {limit:10, start_dt:start_dt},
            error: function (model, response, options) {
                if(response.status == '403') {
                    app.Session.logout();
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a collection for the registration and use the `url` property as a function. By default, the `urlRoot` of the models of the `RegistrationCollection` will be the `url` of the collection with their `id` appended.

```
app.RegistrationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return app.API_server + 'event/' + this.id + '/registrations';
    },
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        options = options || {};
        this.id = options.id;
    }
});
```

Then, on `EventModel` initializing, add a `RegistrationCollection` as a property, passing the event `id` as an option to the collection.

```
app.EventModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: app.API_server + 'event',
    initialize: function() {
        this.registrations = new app.RegistrationCollection(null, {
            id: this.id
        });
    }
});
```

Remove the `fetch` from the init, you want to make your collection reusable.

```
app.EventCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.EventModel,
    url: app.API_server + 'event',
});
```

Fetch inside the view or the router, depending on where it makes more sense for your app.

```
var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new app.EventCollection();
        var dt = new Date(),
            start_dt = dt.toISOString();

        // this should be here, outside of the collection.
        this.collection.fetch({
            data: { limit: 10, start_dt: start_dt },
            error: function(model, response, options) {
                if (response.status === 403) {
                    app.Session.logout();
                }
            }
        });
    },
});
```